# Netgear FVS318g Problem Resolving Local Connections by Name

Tags: domain-name-system, router, netgear, local, resolve

Does anyone know if this router perfoms local dns caching for the DHCP connections it dishes out locally? I cannot seem to access any hosts connected to it by name, although the connected hosts are definitely listed by name on the router status page. I would have thought that was a given today without setting anything up. Other than the DHCP server pointing the router as a dns server that is. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chances are that it isn't doing *anything* with DNS for the local names.  I don't know that specific router, but most just have simple DNS forwarders in them, and aren't clever enough to serve local names.

The entries you can see in the router status table will be just those that the hosts sent in their DHCP REQUEST packets - in effect that page is just a DHCP lease table, and probably nothing to do with DNS.

Answer (score 1):

If it does, it will probably append .local. to the name.  This isn't caching, it acts like it is authoritative for part of .local -- which is totally bogus, but we live in a world where totally bogus and DNS middleware are the same thing.

Comment: Don't get this confused with the Avahi .local domain if your machine is running mDNS.